# The number of countable models

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a countable first order language. For a natural number n, can we find a complete $\mathcal{L}$-Theory $T$ which has exactly n non-isomorphic countable models ?

Comment: Related "http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69/complete-theory-with-exactly-n-countable-models?rq=1"

Answer (score 2):

No, not for $n=2$. A theorem of Vaught says that a complete theory cannot have exactly two nonisomorphic models.  A proof of this can be found in Shawn Hedman's "A First Course in Logic", for example.

Comment: There is also a proof of Vaught's theorem in Chang & Keisler's "Model Theory", Theorem 2.3.15.

Comment: On the other hand, yes for $n\not=2$.